# Sort music by metadata

Tags: music, files

Is there an easy way to organize all my music files by artist, album etc. ?
I would like to organize all the music files in `~/Music` in folders by their metadata.
So the directory structure would look like this:

```
Music/
  Artist name/
    Album name/
      Song.mp3
```

Is there a tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ex Falso](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) will do the job; I use it to retag and rename my library all the time. To do this, select all of your folders containing music on the left, and then select all of the music you want to rename on the bottom. Go to the Rename Files tab and experiment with settings, using the Preview button to see where music will go. When you're satisfied, hit Save and it will organize them all. :)

Comment: Just a note since it wasn't immediately clear from the Ex Falso project page, it is in the repos so you can install it via sudo apt-get install exfalso

Answer (score 5):

Picard can help with this, though I'm sure there's others as well.

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard

Comment: Picard is amazing. I highly recommend you check it out.

Comment: Most of my music is correctly tagged, what I want is to have it all sorted into folders using the metadata. How do I do that with Picard?

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but it took me a little while to figure out how to do it. 1. Add files - this will display the music in the left hand side and will scan metadata. 2. Select the files you want re-organised and click the Lookup toolbar icon - this will add album clusters ot the right hand side. 3. In the options menu, ensure the options rename files, move files are selected. 4. Go to options --> File naming and ensure "Rename files when saving" is selected - apply the changes be clicking OK. 4. With the files/clusters selected in the right hand side, click the Save button.