# Organize Music Folder Automatically

Tags: music, media-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort music by metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7225/sort-music-by-metadata)

Is there any way I can automatically organize my Music folder? Banshee (at least I think it was banshee) moved tons of stuff out of their band/album folders and into the root Music folder and it will drive me crazy until I can fix this.

I'd prefer it to be something that works automatically according to parameters I specified (based on music meta-data). Also, it might need to skip symlinks although this is required.

Comment: Can you give more details about Banshee moving your files? I don't think that's supposed to happen.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it was Banshee or not, but there is a distinct correlation. I typically use Rhythmbox, but wanted to try some alternatives. It was either Banshee or Exaile. I'd imagine it was some sort of "auto manage" feature of one of these.

Comment: Banshee has an option in the 'General' tab of 'Preferences' to "Update file and folder names" which it can do based on the 'File Organisation' preferences in the 'Source Specific' tab.

Comment: Is there any way I can mark this as a duplicate? Because that topic did answer this correctly.