# How can I organize mixed mp3 files in natty?

Tags: mp3-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort music by metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7225/sort-music-by-metadata)

I have missorted the mp3 files into different folders.

- Is it possible to organize all the mp3 files in correct folders ?
- Can I move the files in those folders according to the genre ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Banshee to move the MP3's into a consistent folder structure, although you can't do it by genre. You just need to select "copy files to media folders when importing" in the preferences and make sure the directory you are importing from isn't the same as the directory you are importing to.

Answer (score 0):

Before looking at the brief script below please read these notes about a couple of the lines: Within the MediaMonkey installer I accepted all defaults except on the last page. I Have [the website for mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/download/).

```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   mkdir -p ~/.wine/WineTricks
   cd ~/.wine/WineTricks
   wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
   mkdir -p ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts
   sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6 gecko vb6run wsh56
   sudo apt-get install winbind
   wine /path/to/mediaMonkeyInstaller.exe
```

This may help you. This has been my solution for the same issue . But i'm still looking for a Native App to do the same thing to replace mediamonkey.  [More info](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Linux,_Wine_&_MediaMonkey/).